# Azure Managed Instance Same Query in Row / Batch Mode running in very similar times. Why isn't Batch Mode Running Faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, azure-sql-database, sql-execution-plan

Azure Managed Instance Same Query in Row / Batch Mode running in very similar times. Why isn't Batch Mode Running Faster?
The way I got the Row Mode is running under a database context of compatibility_level = 140 and Batch Mode running under compatibility_level = 150 . Actually Row Mode is running little slower 364 sec vs 346 sec. The query is only using Hash Joins.

[image: Batch Mode Plan]

[image: Batch Mode Numbers]

[image: Row Mode Plan]

[Attached link has the query Plans](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apv4g3d243EpjM5Gg2ybcU9E_XajWg?e=RmxrE5)

Comment: Batch mode over B-Trees can be faster but it is not always.  We have to convert from row mode when scanning storage. Please consider trying with columnstores for some or all of the source structures. Often you don’t need as many indexes (or want them) for analytics heavy databases, but I can’t speculate on the purpose of the workload from your post.

Comment: Thank you. The question was not just for this query (my intentions) but to understand under what condition when NON columnstore indexes used batch/row mode expected to perform and howcome optimizer is not aware row mode could be faster and use row mode (since even cpu utilization of the query is higher when used batch mode). Currently in our Azure Managed instance all databases except system (msdb,master,tempdb,ssisdb) are set to 140 compatibility and we have many adhoc queries similar out there. We want to implement upgrading compatibility level to 150 soon but this case by itself is ...

Comment: making me concerned. Our client in this case has resource governor on cpu utilization etc for regular users and no limit on production processes etc. Most likely they are not going to be able to make an exact throughout test and upgrading to 150 compatibility may end up back firing. I don't want to put query hints to all these queries. How can we move forward in this case. (For them to change tables to columnstore is difficult at this stage, too many dependencies)

Comment: The filter operator after reading from batch mode seems like the bitmap index filtering, my understanding in row mode bitmap index can be applied to bottom during read including other predicates, is batch mode not able to apply the bitmap filter during read and instead bitmap filter needs to be applied to the data during flow?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what kind of queries not using ColumnStore  indexes will benefit from Batch Mode and what to look for in the query plans (ex how do I see conversion from batch to row mode during scanning etc).